# What calls wm8350_i2c_probe() in wm8350-i2c.c?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, i2c, insmod

I'm writing a multi-function kernel driver module, based on http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mfd/wm8350-i2c.c?v=4.4 and http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mfd/wm8350-core.c?v=4.4

I am confused as to how/when/why the `wm8350_i2c_probe()` function is called.

The `i2c_add_driver()` call registers a `struct i2c_driver` with the i2c subsystem and that struct includes a `.probe` pointer to the `wm8350_i2c_probe()` function.

I have made my own analogues of these modules.  The `xxx_i2c_init()` is called on `insmod` but the i2c subsystem does not call the `xxx_i2c_probe()` function.

There is something I do not understand here.  Why doesn't the i2c subsystem call the `wm8350_i2c_probe()` function via the registered `.probe`?

Comment: What resource provider do you use? Device tree, ACPI, platform data (board files)?

Comment: @SamProtsenko I think that the wm8350 uses data from board files.  Are http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-imx/mach-mx31ads.c?v=4.4#L495 and http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-s3c64xx/mach-smdk6410.c?v=4.4#L492 board files?

Comment: Yes, those are board files. Which exactly kernel and platform/board you use?

Comment: The function is called by device driver core. Perhaps you may start from *drivers/base/dd.c*.

Comment: @SamProtsenko Kernel 4.4 and It's a custom ARM board that I'm bringing up (only four in the world, so far).  I think I need to write a board file for this board to declare the bus number and address of the i2c chip.  (I haven't done any kernel work in 10+ years so I'm very rusty.)

Comment: @chrisdew In kernel 4.4 you expected to create Device Tree (`.dts`) instead of board files for ARM boards. Look at `arch/arm/boot/dts/`. Compiled Device Tree (`.dtb`) is being read by bootloader (U-Boot) to RAM, modified slightly, and passed to kernel via `r2` register . In your driver you should use corresponding `of_*` functions to obtain properties for your device from Device Tree.

Comment: @chrisdew Take a look here: ["Device Tree for Dummies"](http://free-electrons.com/pub/conferences/2013/elce/petazzoni-device-tree-dummies/petazzoni-device-tree-dummies.pdf) and here: ["Porting Linux on an ARM board"](http://free-electrons.com/pub/conferences/2015/captronic/captronic-porting-linux-on-arm.pdf) for starters.